# Create relationship betweeen content type and custom entity on specific field

Tags: 8, views, entities

I want to create a two-way relationship between a field in a custom entity (*package_date*) and the field in a content type (*package*).

I have been able to add a relationship from a view for *package_date*, but it only allows me to add the linked field to the view, not any other *package_date* field. When the view is saved, I get this error.

> No entity type for field field_package_id on view package_dates in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\HandlerBase->getEntityType() (line 697 of core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\HandlerBase.php)

The *package_date* entity definition is the following.

```php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;

/**
 * Defines the PackageDate entity.
 *
 * @ingroup package_date
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "package_date",
 *   label = @Translation("Package Date"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData",
 *   },
 *   base_table = "package_date",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 *   admin_permission = "administer package_date entity",
 *   fieldable = true,
 * )
 */

class PackageDate extends ContentEntityBase {

    use EntityChangedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Define the field properties here.
   *
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

        // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
            ->setLabel(t('ID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Term entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

        // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
            ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the Contact entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['package_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Package ID'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'integer',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

        $fields['start_datetime'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
        ->setLabel('Package Start Time')
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'weight' => 1,
        ))
        ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'datetime')
        ->setSetting('timezone_override', '');

        $fields['end_datetime'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
        ->setLabel('Package End Time')
        ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
            'label' => 'above',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'weight' => 2,
        ))
        ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'datetime')
        ->setSetting('timezone_override', '');

    $fields['price'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('decimal')
      ->setLabel(t('Package Price'))
      ->setSettings(array(
          'precision' => 10,
          'scale' => 4,
          'decimal_separator' => '.',
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'decimal',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['capacity'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Capacity'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'integer',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['availability'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Availability'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'integer',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

The `hook_view_data()` implementation uses the following code.

```php
function my_module_views_data() {
  $data['package_date']['table']['group'] = t('Package Dates');

  $data['package_date']['table']['join'] = array(
    // Index this array by the table name to which this table refers.
    // 'left_field' is the primary key in the referenced table.
    // 'field' is the foreign key in this table.
    'node__field_package_id' => array(
      'left_field' => 'field_package_id_value',
      'field' => 'package_id',
    ),
  );

  $data['package_date']['package_id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Package ID'),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node__field_package_id', // The name of the table to join with.
      'base field' => 'field_package_id_value', // The name of the field on the joined table.
      // 'field' => 'package_id' -- see hook_views_data_alter(); not needed here.
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('Relationship between Package and Package Dates'),
      'title' => t('Package to Package Dates Relationship'),
      'id' => 'standard',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

The exported view is the following one.

```yaml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - system.menu.admin
  module:
    - datetime
    - pve
    - user
id: _package_dates
label: 'Package Dates'
module: views
description: 'Display current cache of  Package Dates'
tag: ''
base_table: _package_date
base_field: id
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access site reports'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 50
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          tags:
            previous: ‹‹
            next: ››
            first: '« First'
            last: 'Last »'
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          quantity: 9
      style:
        type: table
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        _package_id:
          table: _package_date
          field: _package_id
          id: _package_id
          entity_type: null
          entity_field: _package_id
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Package ID'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        start_datetime:
          id: start_datetime
          table: _package_date
          field: start_datetime
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Package Start Time'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: datetime_default
          settings:
            timezone_override: ''
            format_type: medium
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: start_datetime
          plugin_id: field
        end_datetime:
          id: end_datetime
          table: _package_date
          field: end_datetime
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Package End Time'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: datetime_default
          settings:
            timezone_override: ''
            format_type: medium
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: end_datetime
          plugin_id: field
        availability:
          id: availability
          table: _package_date
          field: availability
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: Availability
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings:
            thousand_separator: ''
            prefix_suffix: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: availability
          plugin_id: field
        capacity:
          id: capacity
          table: _package_date
          field: capacity
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: Capacity
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: number_integer
          settings:
            thousand_separator: ''
            prefix_suffix: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: capacity
          plugin_id: field
        created:
          id: created
          table: _package_date
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: Created
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: medium
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: field
        changed:
          id: changed
          table: _package_date
          field: changed
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: Changed
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: medium
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: changed
          plugin_id: field
      filters: {  }
      sorts: {  }
      title: 'Package Dates'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty:
        area_text_custom:
          id: area_text_custom
          table: views
          field: area_text_custom
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          empty: true
          tokenize: false
          content: '<p>There is currently no data to display.</p>'
          plugin_id: text_custom
      relationships:
        _package_id:
          id: _package_id
          table: _package_date
          field: _package_id
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: 'Relationship between Package and Package Dates'
          required: false
          entity_type: _package_date
          entity_field: _package_id
          plugin_id: standard
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: 0
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  _package_dates_report:
    display_plugin: page
    id: _package_dates_report
    display_title: 'Package Dates'
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: admin/-package-dates
      menu:
        type: normal
        title: 'Package Dates'
        description: ''
        expanded: false
        parent: system.admin_reports
        weight: 0
        context: '0'
        menu_name: admin
      display_description: ''
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: 0
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```

It looks like the *relationships* property is the wrong way around, but I'm not sure.

I'd also like to be able to create a view for the *package* content type, and link this to the *package_date* entity. When trying to do so, I don't have a relationship I can add.

I expect I'm missing one or more things to get this working, but I'm not sure what. At the very least, I think I need the inverse of the defined relationship, but I'm sure that's not the only issue.

Comment: Keen to know how this would work, I have posted similar questions, but no answers on those yet.

Comment: Since optimo_package_date is your own custom entity, you can use `hook_views_data` instead of `hook_views_data_alter`. `hook_views_data_alter` would only be required to change node's implementation of hook_views_data (eg. to allow a node to reference your custom entity). In a `hook_views_data_alter` implementation you have to specify the `field` (which is currently missing). If I get it right the date entity contains a reference to the node. In that case the 'base field' should be the identifier of the node, which is `nid`. Otherwise the reference structure is not clear to me.

Comment: I changed back to using `hook_views_data` but no change to the behaviour unfortunately. The relationship between my `package_date` entity and the `package` content type is represented by an integer field in `package_date` and a multiple value integer field in `package` - as stated in my question, it's not an entity relationship.

Comment: @BrynJ, apologies I missed that. I assumed you had one integer field referring to a node id. I have no idea how to approach this with two fields unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

You have actually provided both relationships correctly;

- `$data['package_date']['table']['join']` provides an automatic reference from the external entity to this one; when the other entity is loaded, this one is always available.
- `$data['package_date']['package_id']['relationship']` provides a relationship that needs to be added manually via the views UI.

(If you want them to behave similar, you would have to use [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/8.2.x)) to add one of the above definitions (automatic or manual) to the node entity.)

What I think your problem here (mostly based on Drupal 7 logic), is that you are referring the wrong table. When looking at the [complete list of invocations of hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/implementations/hook_views_data/8.2.x) and for instance look at [`book_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!book!book.views.inc/function/book_views_data/8.2.x), you will see that all those implementations look like this:

```
$data['book']['table']['join'] = [
  'node_field_data' => [
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'nid',
  ],
];
```

All those joins use the `node_field_data` table, not the field specific table `node__field_package_id` you are using:

```
$data['package_date']['table']['join'] = array(
  // Index this array by the table name to which this table refers.
  // 'left_field' is the primary key in the referenced table.
  // 'field' is the foreign key in this table.
  'node__field_package_id' => array(
    'left_field' => 'field_package_id_value',
    'field' => 'package_id',
  ),
);
```

By providing the value for `left_field`, you are already telling Views to which field you want to use, you you should not access that field directly. I suppose it should work once you change `node__field_package_id` to `node_field_data`.